# Identify special characters in Excel based on column names

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I found a code that uses `RegEx` to determine if there are any special characters in a column. I have just found out about `RegEx` today and I tried editing this code but I have encountered 3 problems:

1. It uses `"ActiveSheet"` but I have read that it might cause problems. I would like it to only check the worksheet named `"Consolidated."` I tried `Worksheets.("Consolidated").Range` in the For Each line but it doesn't accept it.
2. This applies to the whole worksheet. I would like to know if it's possible to apply it to a column based on it's name (ex: First Name) and not on it's range because the columns are not fixed in the consolidated worksheet.
3. It also highlights the 1st row where the column names are located (which should not happen). I do get the logic or the workflow of this but I'm new to vba so I would really like to ask guidance on this.

---

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^a-z0-9-]"
Dim regEx As Object
Dim Cell As Range

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.Global = True
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Pattern = strPattern

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z") ' Define your own range here
    If strPattern <> "" Then              ' If the cell is not empty
        If regEx.Test(Cell.Value) Then    ' Check if there is a match
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6  ' If yes, change the background color
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the Changes.

- Use `Find` function to locate the column. used cnum for that
- Use `Worksheets("Consolidated")` without the `.`
- Pass the column number found to the loop range

  ```
  Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^a-z0-9-]"
  Dim regEx As Object
  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim cnum As Integer

  Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  regEx.Global = True
  regEx.IgnoreCase = True
  regEx.Pattern = strPattern

  cnum = Worksheets("Consolidated").Range("A1:Z1").Find("First Name").Column 'column number to search in

  For Each Cell In Worksheets("Consolidated").Range(Cells(2, cnum), Cells(1000, cnum))
      If strPattern <> "" Then              ' If the cell is not empty
          If regEx.Test(Cell.Value) Then    ' Check if there is a match
              Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6  ' If yes, change the background color
          End If
      End If
  Next
  ```

Comment: This code is working perfectly. Just realized that I wasn't passing the correct parameters in the Range method (probably why my attempts are resulting in an error). Just need to put cnum in a loop to put all the values and it's all set. I appreciate the help, Mikku!

Comment: Happy to help :)